# How can I add a deserializer for deserializing values of String-typed fields with a specific name using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

1- Is there a way to add a deserializer to a module or an `ObjectMapper` that gets picked up for deserializing all fields with a specific name or regex pattern? (e.g. all fields that match the `.*url.*` pattern?

2- Also is it possible to register a deserializer that gets picked up for deserializing all fields that have a value that matches a specific regex pattern? (e.g. `http://.+`).

3- Alternatively is there an annotation I can use on a class, rather than registering it with an `ObjectMapper`, that can be used instead of 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a bean serialization customizer that inspects the properties of beans, applies your regular expression, and installs your custom serializer as appropriate.

To quote Tatu:

> The extension point would be to add a BeanSerializerModifier, which
>   you can do via Module implementation. SimpleModule does not add
>   convenience method for this, so you need to implement
>   Module#setupModule(), call 'addBeanSerializerModifier'.

There is a parallel structure for the deserialization side.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for "deserialization" thoguh. I think that should be similar. I'll have a look later when I go back home. P.S: I initially thought you are quoting a Chinese philosopher!

Answer (score 0):

For (1) and (2), no.

For 3, you can override specified Serializer or Deserializer to use for a property, with:

```
public class POJO {
  @JsonSerialize(using=MySerializer.class)
  public String text;
}
```

What you can do for (1) is just to register a custom serializer for `String.class`, and defined it as `ContextualSerializer`. When its `createContextual()` method gets called, you can check which property it is used for; if name matches your regex, you can construct alternative String serializer; if not, simple one that just calls `JsonGenerator.writeString()`.

For (2), you would just defined custom String serializer and compare value during serialization, taking appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I currently am doing, but not what I am asking for in `3.`. In `3.` I am asking for an annotation to be put on the `POJO` that deserialzes all fields that their key (property) name contains "url" to be using a given deserializer. The deserializer should also be picked up by all sub-pojos of the `POJO` instance.

Comment: There is no such annotation or functionality, so you would have to implement something for this yourself.

Comment: What about com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module.SetupContext#addBeandeSerializerModifier? He could wrap every single bean ...

Comment: Sure, that is possible. But I was guessing he wanted something "out of the box". So yes totally possible, some work.